# Fetch API Data in React

Tags: reactjs

I am calling fetchData(url) to retrieve json data. My API data format is like this:
    PageNo:1
    PageSize:100
    PageCount:5
    TotalRecordCount:600
    Items:
     0: {
        ID: 1,
        SUBJECT: ACC
        }
     1: {…}

My react ItemList.js:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
class ItemList extends Component{
constructor(){
    super();
    this.state={
        Items:[],
        hasErrored: false,
        isLoading: false
    };
}
 //retrieve data using fetch
 fetchData(url){
    this.setState({isLoading: true});
    fetch(url)
    .then((response)=>{
        if (!response.ok){
            throw Error(response.statusText);
        }
        this.setState({isLoading:false});
        return response;
    })


    .then((response)=>{response.Items.json()})
    .then((Items)=>{
         this.setState({Items});

    })
    .catch(()=>this.setState({hasErrored:true}));
}
componentDidMount(){
    this.fetchData(myURL)
}

render(){
    if (this.state.hasErrored){
        return <p>There was an error loading the items</p>;
    }
    if (this.state.isLoading){
        return <p>Loading...</p>;
    }

    return(
        <div>  
        <ul>

            {this.state.Items.map((item)=>(
                <li key={item.ID}>{item.SUBJECT}</li>
            ))}
        </ul>
        </div>
    );
  }
  }
export default ItemList;
```

It always returns "There was an error loading the items". The Items array is always empty. But if I copy and paste the api url to browser, it works fine. Not sure what is wrong with my code? Thanks.

Comment: Your call enters the `catch` block. Start from there. Add the error parameter inside the `catch(()=>` like `catch((error)=>` and check that. Also, you can use inspect element and look at your request in `Network` tab.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> response.Items.json()

This line will throw an error as when you're accessing to the response it is yet just a string before converting it to JSON format

use

> response.json()

Then, I'll change a bit @Kabbany answer as response.statusText always returns the generic error message associated with the error code. Most APIs, however, will generally return some kind of useful, more human friendly message in the body.

The key is that rather than throwing an error, you just throw the response and then process it in the catch block to extract the message in the body:

```
fetch(url)
      .then( response => {
        if (!response.ok) { throw response } // Return the complete error response for debugging purposes
        return response.json()  //we only get here if there is no error
      })
      .then( json => {
        this.setState({Items: json.Items }); 
      })
      .catch( error => {
        () => this.setState({ hasErrored: true, error }) // Save both error flag and error detail so you can send it to tools like bugsnag
      })
```

Answer (score -1):

I think it should look like this:

```
fetch(url)
.then((response)=>{
    if (!response.ok){
        throw Error(response.statusText);
    }
    this.setState({isLoading:false});
    return response.json();
})
.then((resp)=>{
     this.setState({Items: resp.Items});
})
.catch(()=>this.setState({hasErrored:true}));
```

Comment: Thanks but I tried Items: resp.Items and it doesn't work.

Comment: anyway you are missing a big part which is `response.json()`, if it is not there the response won't be available in json format